# Measurement operators: singularity and other restrictions?

Tags: quantum-information

A posulatuate used in  Nielsen & Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*:

Quantum measurements are described by a collection $\{M_m \}$ of
measurement operators. These are operators acting on the state space of the
system being measured. The index $m$ refers to the measurement outcomes that
may occur in the experiment. If the state of the quantum system is $|\psi\rangle$
immediately before the measurement then the probability that result $m$ occurs is:
$$p(m) = \langle\psi| M_m^{\dagger} M_m|\psi\rangle  $$

and the state of the system after the measurement is
$$ \frac{M_m|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(m)}} $$

As the $p(m)$ must sum to one, the measurement operators must satisfy the completeness equation,
$$\sum M_m^{\dagger} M_m = I$$

No other restraints are noted for these measurement operators.

---

The operators are not explicitly required to be singular, which caught my attention.

Let's say I have a set of $\{M_m \}$ measurement operators which describe some measurement, $M$. For some other measurement, $N$, I have a set of $\{N_n \}$ measurement operators describing it. It so happens that the operator $N_b = M^{-1}_a$ for a specific $b$ and $a$.

Upon making my first measurement, $M$, on an ensemble of states all in $|\psi\rangle$, some fraction, $p(a)$, of them end up in the state: $$ |\psi^{'}\rangle = \frac{M_a|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(a)}} $$
On these states I choose to make my measurement $N$. Some fraction, $p(b)$, of them end up in the state:
$$|\psi^{''}\rangle = \frac{N_b|\psi^{'}\rangle}{\sqrt{p(b)}} $$
$$ = \frac{N_b M_a |\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(b)p(a)}} = \frac{M^{-1}_a M_a |\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(b)p(a)}} = \frac{|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(b)p(a)}}$$

$$ |\psi^{''}\rangle = \frac{|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{p(b)p(a)}} $$

---

This *would* be an interesting result, suggesting that if I perform two measurements some fraction of the time, $p(a)p(b)$, I could return to the initial state *and* have obtained the knowledge of $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ along the way. Of course, since the division by $\sqrt{p(a \text{ or } b)}$ is supposed to serve as normalization term, the final result suggests that this process only works in the trivial case $p(a) = p(b) = 1$. I.e. $M_{a} = N_{b} = I$.

By contradiction (I guess?) it's shown that measurement operators $\{ M_{m} \}$ must **all** be singular. Or, at least, the inverse of any $M_m$ cannot be a member of any other set of measurement operators.

Had I been careful, I imagine this result could have been found by looking at the completeness equation directly.

**Question:** how could the singularity of all $\{ M_{m} \}$ be shown from the completeness relation and, further, are there any authors who go into the limitations on $\{ M_{m} \}$?

Comment: I've realized it is untrue that the measurement operators must all be singular. In fact, it _is_ true that the inverses of  M_m cannot be a member of any other set of operators, but the inverse over some n>1 **can** be. The above process would then seem possible. Which I find interesting.